# Require year-month-day selection ordering in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery datepicker. My requirement is that the user should only be able to select Year first than Month and than day. This is for date of birth capturing. Please help me. That is because users while selecting their DOB are not selecting year of birth which is then taken as default and thus there's loss of business and revenue.

Comment: You should really provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of datepicker, you should probably switch to separate controls for each input parameter. Then on submit, validate that all fields are entered.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, so that the calendar is restricted to display date greater than today.

$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

showOn: "focus",
yearRange: "1970:2017",
dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
changeYear: true,
changeMonth: true,
showMonthAfterYear: true,
maxDate:0
});
});

But still, if we select day, the calendar disappears, and we have to click the box for the datepicker to select year and month again.